# How to return Name with its specific ID?

Tags: mysql, sql, select, innodb

Suppose we have a table like this

```
+------------+-----------+
| EmployeeID | Name      |
+------------+-----------+
|          1 | Peter     |          
|          2 | John      |   
|          3 | Henry     |
```

And now I want to return all the name with their primary key. Peter(1),John(2),Henry(3),...

```
    +------------+
    | Test       |
    +------------+
    |   Peter(1) |      
    |    John(2) |   
    |   Henry(3) |
```

I tried some specific SELECT statements but I didn't get the result I wanted

Comment: This is an odd request

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `CONCAT` function of mysql:

```
SELECT CONCAT(A.Name, '(', A.EmployeeID, ')') AS Test FROM myTable AS A;
```

Answer (score 1):

Use concat to join strings together.

```
SELECT 
    Concat(`Name`,'(', employeeID, ')') AS EmployeeWithId
FROM EmployeeTable
```

Beware, concat will return null if any of the used columns are null.

On the other hand, `concat_ws(delimiter, string1, string2)` will return a string even if any of the used columns are `null`.

```
SELECT 
    concat_ws('',`Name`,'(', employeeID, ')') AS EmployeeWithId
FROM EmployeeTable
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want the string formatted  ad Name(1)  you could use concat

```
select  concat(Name, '(',EmployeeID,')')  test
from myTable
```